# Как получить данные об авторизованном пользователе Yii в Websocket?

Tags: yii2, консоль, websocket, users, workerman

Я использую https://github.com/walkor/Workerman
В связке с Yii2

Мне необходимо сделать следующее: чтобы на сервере можно было определить авторизован пользователь или нет и получить данные о нем, например логин, но... веб сокет запущен через консоль. а в кжонсоле пользователь не авторизован, он авторизован в web.
Как можно это реализовать ?
Передавать по сокету данные о пользователе(типа id) не вариант. И токен тоже, так как можно же его перехватить, и дальше использовать

Comment: Почему id не вариант? Надо же как-то определять юзера в любом случае.В БД хранить сессию и по айди проверять ее.

Comment: Сделайте для каждого авторизованного пользователя генерируемый при каждом обращении уникальный URL. Например : `site/logged/<md5>` естественно значение <md5> храните в `БД`. По нему и определяйте какой именно это пользователь. Так как `URL` уникальный, генерируется при каждом запросе заново, да еще и 32-символа то подобрать его не будет возможности.